# Use RegEx to find and transform characters to capital case

Tags: regex, notepad++

In **notepad++** I need to use `RegEx` transform all

```
phone1_id, phone2_id, phone3_id
in

PHONE1_ID, PHONE2_ID, PHONE3_ID
```

This `RegEx` helps me find all those `strings: phone\d+_id`
but how can I transform them to capital case?

Comment: you can try using ctrl+shift+u

Comment: @inneedofhelp the strings to transform in capital case where in a very big chunk of text so I could not select them one by one. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `phone\d+_id`
- Replace with: `\U$0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Replacement:**

```
\U  : Change to uppercase
$0  : contains the whole match
```

**Result for given example:**

```
PHONE1_ID, PHONE2_ID, PHONE3_ID
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you :)